# org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, mockito

I've looked at a number of related questions on Stack Overflow but haven't found a match.

I'm using Mockito and trying to create a custom argument matcher for a method that has the following signature.

```
public ClusterViewMember getPersonWithTreeInfo(Gid clusterGid, Gid memberGid, boolean retBlob) throws Exception
```

The code fails with an "InvalidUseOfMatchersException"  The entire exception message is:

```
Method threw 'org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.xxx.yyy.services.pm3cache.provider.PmCacheProvider$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$c81cff41.toString()
```

The code line fails with a null pointer exception.  I find the Mockito exception by stepping through in debug mode.  The individual line of code is below.

```
when(pmCacheProvider.getPersonWithTreeInfo(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(new ClusterViewMember());
```

Finally - the entire test method is below.

2 Notes:

1. Execution does not get past the "when" line - that is where the error occurs.
2. The method in Foo (provider) that I'm calling ends up calling the method I'm writing the custom matcher for.  In other words "getMemberData()" ends up calling "getPersonWIthTreeInfo()"

```
@Test
public void testGetMemberData()
      throws Exception {

    Gid memberGid = new Gid("1:2");
    Gid clusterGid = new Gid("3:4");
    boolean retBlob = true;

    Pm3CacheDataProviderMetricsTestImpl metrics = new Pm3CacheDataProviderMetricsTestImpl();
    PmCacheProvider pmCacheProvider = mock(PmCacheProvider.class);

    when(pmCacheProvider.getPersonWithTreeInfo(any(), any(), any())).thenReturn(new ClusterViewMember());

    Foo provider = new Foo(pmCacheProvider,metrics);
    ClusterViewMember cvm = provider.getMemberData(clusterGid, memberGid, retBlob);

    AssertJUnit.assertNotNull(cvm);

    assertTrue(metrics.getRecordGetMemberData() > 0);
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem lies in the last parameter of your method which of type `boolean`.

Now, `AgumentMatchers.any()` is well suited for the first two params as they are objects.

It is not suited for a primitive type.

Try using `anyBoolean()` and also add specific class epxectations for the first two params:

```
when(pmCacheProvider.getPersonWithTreeInfo(any(Gid.class), any(Gid.class), anyBoolean()))
```

Comment: Alternatively you could also use `any(Boolean.class)` for the last one.

Comment: Thank you!  That was exactly it.